# convert an isoformat string to python datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse ISO formatted date in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-iso-formatted-date-in-python)

I have an isoformat datetime as a string like the example below -

```
'2011-05-31T04:35:33.127-05:00'
```

What is the best way convert it to a python datetime object? I came across some posts that tell how to get an isoformat string but not the other way round.

Thanks!!

**Edit based on Yan's comment-**

```
>>>import dateutil.parser
>>> d1='2011-05-31T04:35:33.127-05:00'
>>> d2=dateutil.parser.parse(d1)
>>> d2
datetime.datetime(2011, 5, 31, 4, 35, 33, 127000, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
```

I need to get the datetime object for the local time represented by the original string. Since I do not know which timezone the input date was in, I cannot use the astimezon method. What will be the best way to get that?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There is an strptime function, just like in C.
http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: Thanks letibee for your response, but unfortunately datetime.datetime.strptime does not work well for the isoformat date string. Thanks Yan, yes I want something like dateutil parser. I have edited my original question. Is there a way to the local time using tzoffset?